# turnip - is there a pretty formatter?

Tags: ruby, rspec

while developing tests it's nice to see the test  steps  printed  pretty,  much like cucumber.

when I  run tests  with --format  documentation  it prints out like  this

```
I  go  to the  messages  page -> I  should  see page  title "messages" -> I  should  see  today's  date
```

is there a  formatter that  works  to produce output  more like  cucumber --format  pretty?

I  couldn't find any sample out put from  turnip  to know if what I'm  seeing us what I  should  expect.

Answer (score 0):

I've released [turnip_formatter](https://github.com/gongo/turnip_formatter).

### Installation.

```
$ gem install turnip_formatter
```

### Usage

```
$ rspec -r turnip_formatter --format RSpecTurnipFormatter --out report.html
```

And open "report.html", can view pretty format HTML.

Use this, can be easily viewed multiple steps (passed, failed and pending).

Please try.Thanks